# Having to log In twice after screen lockout

Tags: 10.04, login, lock-screen

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS Desktop. (And by scanning /boot, it appears I *might* be on kernel 2.6.32-29-generic? Not certain.)

Anyway, after my last system update, now my screen lock asks me to login twice, whereas before it did not require this.

I assume this is a bug? And is there a way to undo this for now until the bug is fixed?

Comment: Do you mean what happens when you click lock screen from the system menu? Or are you switching users?

Comment: I have my screensaver set to do a screen lock when idle. When I wiggle my mouse, I see the login for the screen lock. I type in my password, and then it goes black and asks me yet again. Clearly this is a bug with the latest Ubuntu update because that's the only thing major I've really done. It just started occurring yesterday after my most recent Ubuntu update.

Comment: For now, I have turned off my screen lock in the screensaver. I hate that, though. I highly value my screen lock.

Comment: I have this issue too.  When the machine is idle and the locking screensaver active, and the password is entered, the desktop appears as it should but only for about a second, then it goes back to being screensaver locked.  On the second try it is unlocked.  My Linux Mint (ubuntu 10 based) on an ASUS eeePC did this for a while intermittently. Have you tried doing an apt-get upgrade to see if someone else has posted fixes?

Comment: @Paul. Tried doing the "apt-get update; apt-get upgrade", and that didn't work. Rebooted. Didn't work. Tried more apt upgrades. Didn't work. Also, I'm only doing a screen dim -- no screensaver. And when I turned off the screen lock, I get this problem where I can't type anything in Chrome and must shut down Chrome and come back again.

Comment: same issue on 15.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough updates with "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade" and reboots, Ubuntu finally must have fixed this bug because I no longer have to login twice after a screen lockout timer engages from the screensaver. Also, it used to be that Chrome would lockup on the keystrokes after unlocking a screen, but that problem went away as well. Also, I appear to still be on the same kernel as when the problem occurred: kernel 2.6.32-29-generic.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Gnome's screensaver seems to be active too. Uninstall it if you're fully on board with MATE:

> `sudo apt-get remove gnome-scrensaver`

This may require a reboot to take effect